# Haskell FFI local c header

Tags: haskell

I want to call a C single header library with FFI.

Here's the `Nuk.hs`

```
{-# LANGUAGE CPP, ForeignFunctionInterface #-}
module Main where

import Foreign
import Foreign.C.Types

foreign import ccall unsafe "nuklear.h nk_sin"
 c_nk_sin:: IO CFloat

main = print $ c_nk_sin (5)
```

In the same directory, I have the `nuklear.h`

When I do `stack ghc Nuk.hs`, I get

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( Nuk.hs, Nuk.o )
Linking Nuk ...
Nuk.o:r1Rq_info: error: undefined reference to 'nk_sin'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
`gcc' failed in phase `Linker'. (Exit code: 1)
```

How should I solve this?

Comment: Do you have a `.o` file with the C side binary? You need to link that together e.g. `stack ghc Nuk.hs cside.o`. If you do not want to link, instead, use `-c`. (And link afterwards)

Comment: @chi, I don't. The C side is a single header file that should be included in C programs. The implementations are also inside that header file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it’s a header-only library, you need a C compiler to produce an object file for it so that your Haskell program can link to the definitions. According to the documentation for Nuklear, you can create a stub C file:

```
// nuklear.c
#define NK_IMPLEMENTATION
#include "nuklear.h"
```

As part of your build, compile this (e.g. with `gcc -c nuklear.c -o nuklear.o`) to produce an object file `nuklear.o`, use `ar` (e.g. `ar -csr libnuklear.a nuklear.o`) to create a static library `libnuklear.a`, then supposing this archive is in `libs`, you would add:

```
extra-lib-dirs: libs
extra-libraries: nuklear
```

To the `executable` section in your Cabal file. (Or the corresponding section in `package.yml` for hpack.)

To coordinate this, you might have a Makefile that builds this library and also invokes `stack`/`cabal`/`ghc` to produce the final build result. [This tutorial](http://www.the-efficient-programmer.com/programming/link-c-lib-in-haskell.html) covers the process in a little more explicit detail. But for this simple use case, you may be able to just use the [`c-sources` section](https://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/developing-packages.html#pkg-field-c-sources) to do this from within Cabal:

```
c-sources: nuklear.c
```

You may also need to specify `includes` and `include-dirs`, e.g.:

```
includes: nuklear.h
```

Comment: How about using inline-c?